# Solving differential equation by weak formulation and minimizing a functional

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I want to give a weak formulation of the boundary value problem
\begin{align*}
 -(c(x)(u'(x)-1))' & = 0 \textrm{ on } \Omega = (-1,1) \\
  u(-1) = u(1) & = 0
\end{align*}
where $c(x)$ is piecewise linear. Then solve the weak problem for
$$
 c(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \cosh(\pi) & -1 < x < 0 \\
                                 \sinh(\pi) & 0 \le x < 1 \end{array}\right.
$$
I have some questions on my approach, and at a few points I am totally unsure if I am on the right track. First for the weak formulation I define the functional
$$
 a(u,v) := \int_{-1}^1 -(c(x)(u'(x)-1))' v(x)  d x
$$
on the space of all continuous functions with $v(-1) = v(1) = 0$. Then by partial integration I get
$$
 a(u,v) = \int_{-1}^1 c(x)(u'(x)-1) v'(x) d x.
$$
But this is not symmetric? In my notes the functional has to be symmetric? Okay, but to proceed, the weak formulations looks for a function $u$ such that
$$
 a(u,v) = 0
$$
for all $v$ with $v(-1) = v(1) = 0$. Okay I consider the functional
$$
 E(v) = \frac{a(v,v)}{2} = \int_{-1}^1 c(x)(v'(x) - 1)v'(x) d x.
$$
This functional has to be minimized now. To solve this, I should also suppose that $u$ is continuous and linear on $[-1,0]$ and linear on $[0,1]$, this means that $u$ has the form
\begin{align*}
 u(x) & = a x + b \mbox{ for } x \in [-1,0] \\
 u(x) & = c x + d \mbox{ for } x \in [0,1].
\end{align*}
So this means I have to minimize $E(u)$ over the space of all such functions with $u(-1) = u(1)$? Is this all right? And what about the fact that $a(u,v)$ is not symmetric?

Comment: Your weak forumlation looks fine, but notice that the bilinear form $a$ is not the Euler-Lagrange equation for your functional $E$. Also, why do you assume $u$ to be linear on $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$?

Comment: Because it is given that I have to look in this function space. The Euler-Lagrange equation is the original ODE I guess, or not?

Answer (score 0):

$$ -(c(x)(u'(x)-1))'  =0$$
$$ c(x)u''(x) =0 $$

Multiply both sides by $v(x)\in H^1_0([-1,1])$ and integrate by parts:
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} c(x)u''(x) v(x)dx=0$$
$$ [c(x)v(x)u'(x)]_{-1}^{1}-\int_{-1}^{1} c(x)u'(x) v'(x)dx=0$$
Due to essential boundary conditions the boundary term vanishes; leaving behind.
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} c(x)u'(x) v'(x)dx=0$$
which of the weak form $A(u,v)=F(v)$. It is possible to argue that this is equivalent to the form where we seek $u(x)$ which minimizes $\frac{1}{2}A(u,u)-F(u)$ using the properties of coercivity of A, continuity of A and F, bilinearity of A, linearity of F, and symmetry of A.